# How to make separate success page for a specific product ordering in magento 1.9.3.1?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout-page

how to add new separate success page for a single product .

Any help would be appreciated..!

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: In seprate success page what you want to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)